# Single Process (Shared-Memory) Multiple-CPU Parallelism in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have used mclapply quite a bit and love it.  It is a memory hog but very convenient.  Alas, now I have a different problem that is not simply embarrassingly parallel.

Can R (esp Unix R) employ multiple CPU cores on a single computer, sharing the same memory space, without resorting to copying full OS processes, so that

1. there is minimal process overhead; and
2. modification of global data by one CPU are immediately available to other CPUs?

If yes, can R lock some memory just like files (flock)?

I suspect that the answer is no and learning this definitively would be very useful.  If the answer is yes, please point me the right way.

regards,

/iaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Rdsm](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rdsm) package to use *distributed* shared memory parallelism, i.e. multiple R processes using the same memory space.

Besides that, you can employ multi-threaded BLAS/LAPACK (e.g. OpenBLAS or Intel MKL) and you can use C/C++ (and probably Fortran) code together with OpenMP. See [assembling a matrix from diagonal slices with mclapply or %dopar%, like Matrix::bandSparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160898/assembling-a-matrix-from-diagonal-slices-with-mclapply-or-dopar-like-matrix/50176588#50176588) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you take a look at Microsoft's R Open (available for Linux), with the custom Math Kernel Library (MKL).
I've seen very good performance improvements without rewriting code.

https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/multithread